# Can IBM MQ internally route messages?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm an IBM MQ novice, however have used other messaging systems in the past (Solace, RabbitMQ, BizTalk). I apologize if some of my MQ terminology is incorrect when it comes to local/remote/transmission queues etc.

I am integrating with a 3rd Party using MQ. I have no control over the use of MQ when it comes to this 3rd party. They define the set integration pattern.

- I have my own local Queue Manager.
- The 3rd party supports many 100s of different message types.
- Typically each message sent to them will result in a response
- Responses on overage will be delivered back to my QM within 0.5s (agreed SLA)

The basic model is as follows;

- For all outbound messaging I publish to a single queue
- All responses come to a single inbound queue on my QM
- I do not believe they respect/use the ReplyToQ or ReplyToQmgr header properties

High level overview of the use case;

- The MQ usage will be very active. Perhaps 500-1000 outbound messages per second
- For the vast majority of these - there will be a user waiting for a response
- The current design approach is to put a message onto the outbound queue and then create a subscription to the inbound queue with a JMS selector using the correlation ID.

Here is my challenge;

- I am not sure if having so many concurrently subscriptions all with a unique filter on the single inbound queue will perform well. I would appreciate insights into this. I have a 2 node cluster running in a docker container. I don't have details on the spec yet.
- My preference would be have messages arrive into the inbound queue and then be routed to many "function" specific local queues on the QM.
- I would still use JMS selectors on the message ID in this model - however I would hope the load would be spread from a single deep queue to many shorter queues
- It does not seem that I could route messages natively within MQ without an addon such as MQ Integration Broker or ESB (some other products within the WebSphere suite).

It is on this last point I could use some guidance. Can I route within my QM? If so - what options do I have. Alternatively - perhaps there are much better approaches that I have not considered?

Any guidance would be heartily appreciated!!

Comment: IBM MQ is designed to be efficient in doing a GET by correlation ID.  MQ can not route responses coming into a single queue into different queues natively.

Comment: In many cases if a application does populate the correlation ID with the original message ID it may mean they would honor ReplyToQueue and ReplyToQmgr, you may want to check with them.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc, much appreciated Yes I will follow up on the use of ReplyToQ and QMgr